# how to get a max per group and subgroup using jq

Tags: json, jq, pgbackrest

jq is an amazing tool and it does a lot.
as input I have

```
[
  {
    "backup": [
      {
        "timestamp": { "start": 1642144383, "stop": 1642144386 },
        "info": {  "size": 1200934840},
        "type": "full"
      },
      {
        "timestamp": {"start": 1642144388, "stop":  1642144392 },
        "info": { "size": 1168586300
        },
        "type": "incr"
      },
      {
        "timestamp": {"start": 1642145388, "stop":  1642145392 },
        "info": { "size": 1168586330
        },
        "type": "incr"
      }
    ],
    "name": "dbname1"
  },
  {
    "backup": [
      {
        "timestamp": { "start": 1642144383, "stop": 1642144386 },
        "info": {  "size": 1200934840},
        "type": "full"
      },
      {
        "timestamp": {"start": 1642144388, "stop":  1642144392 },
        "info": { "size": 1168586300
        },
        "type": "incr"
      }
    ],
    "name": "dbname2"
  }
]
```

and using

```
jq 'map([.backup[] + {name}] | max_by(.timestamp.stop))'
```

I get the latest timestamp.stop for a name. How should I change this to get the latest timestamp.stop for a name and group?
in SQL this would be something like max(.timestamp.stop) group by .name,.type
Hoping for output like:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": {
      "start": 1642144383,
      "stop": 1642144386
    },
    "info": {
      "size": 1200934840
    },
    "type": "full",
    "name": "dbname1"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": {
      "start": 1642145388,
      "stop": 1642145392
    },
    "info": {
      "size": 1168586330
    },
    "type": "incr",
    "name": "dbname1"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": {
      "start": 1642144383,
      "stop": 1642144386
    },
    "info": {
      "size": 1200934840
    },
    "type": "full",
    "name": "dbname2"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": {
      "start": 1642144388,
      "stop": 1642144392
    },
    "info": {
      "size": 1168586300
    },
    "type": "incr",
    "name": "dbname2"
  }
]
```

Comment: yes, that is correct one contains the max .timestamp.stop for the type full, the other contains the max .timestamp.stop for the type incr. There can even be more types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inner brackets to flatten the array, then `group_by` both criteria (which makes your criteria an array), and `map` your `max_by` onto the result array:

```sh
jq 'map(.backup[] + {name}) | group_by([.name, .type]) | map(max_by(.timestamp.stop))'
```

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": {
      "start": 1642144383,
      "stop": 1642144386
    },
    "info": {
      "size": 1200934840
    },
    "type": "full",
    "name": "dbname1"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": {
      "start": 1642145388,
      "stop": 1642145392
    },
    "info": {
      "size": 1168586330
    },
    "type": "incr",
    "name": "dbname1"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": {
      "start": 1642144383,
      "stop": 1642144386
    },
    "info": {
      "size": 1200934840
    },
    "type": "full",
    "name": "dbname2"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": {
      "start": 1642144388,
      "stop": 1642144392
    },
    "info": {
      "size": 1168586300
    },
    "type": "incr",
    "name": "dbname2"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1kW3ilKdsT)

Comment: Thanks again! Amazing tool jq. There is still a lot to learn before I am on par with my SQL knowledge.